# How to place Chapter Name in fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, chapters, fancyhdr

I am using the book format and have recently changed my sections to chapters, and subsections to sections etc.

Previously I had the section names in the header, but now I want the chapter names in the header. However, when I changed my fancyhdr commands it still includes the section names and not the chapter names. Here is my code:

```
% Page Headers and Footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\fontfamily{qhv}\selectfont \rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\fontfamily{qhv}\selectfont Report}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\fontfamily{qhv}\selectfont \copyright 2017}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\fontfamily{qhv}\selectfont \thepage}
```

I just replaced `\sectionmark` with `\chaptermark`, and believe it has to be `\markboth` but are confused how to achieve what I want.

Comment: Remove the line that redefines chaptermark and use `\leftmark`  for the outer head.

Comment: Is there any news here?